# How to ignore case when parsing with simplexml?

Tags: php, xml, object, simplexml

can I make simple XML ignore case of the node and attributes names?

like

```
<eleMent attriBute="aaa">

</ELEMENT>
```

Comment: No.. have you did your own testing?

Comment: I tried different cases and parsing failed

Comment: it has to be case sensitive , that is the way xml works

Comment: It's [not supposed to be](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000354.html) case-insensitive.  (tl;dr -- making unicode case-insensitive is too much of a performance hit).

Comment: I see... thanks. I guess my question can be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I make simple XML ignore case of the node and attributes names?

No.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see is to change the case of the xml string you want to parse before the call of `SimpleXMLElement`. Something like this :

```
$content = mb_strtolower(file_get_contents('myfile.xml'), 'UTF-8');
$simpleXmlElement = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
```

Be aware that you will have performance issue using this method with big XML.