# cannot read web service response in php

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap-client

I'm calling a web service in PHP and am having difficulties dealing with the response.

If I do a var_dump of the response, here is the message returned by the web service:

```
     stdClass Object
(
    [webserviceaction] => stdClass Object
        (
            [any] => 

<result xmlns="" corpname="test"><user id="tester">
<inbox><actionitems><title>View transcript</title>
<actionitemurl>../MainView.aspx?tab_page_id=-8&amp;Reset=TRUE</actionitemurl>
</actionitems><actionitems>
.....
</result>
```

tried to read the corpname as

```
$getUser->Webserviceaction->Result['corpName'];
```

It displays NULL. Not sure how to read an xml that's inside an object.

Tried to get the lastresponse as per http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10370637-Cannot-read-web-service-response

Not able to get the values still.
Here is the code.

```
echo "RESPONSE:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n";
$xmlstring = $getUser->webserviceaction->any;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);


foreach ($xml->result->user->inbox->actionitems as $res)
    echo "Title" . $res->title . "\n";
```

Please advise.

This is what I see when I print the $xml

```
 resultobject(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["corpName"]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
  ["User"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (4) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(6) "tester"
    }
    ["Inbox"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (1) {
      ["ActionItems"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (2) {
          ["Title"]=>
          string(15) "View transcript"
          ["ActionItemUrl"]=>
          string(46) "../MainView.aspx?tab_page_id=-8&amp;Reset=TRUE"
        }
        [1]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (2) {
          ["Title"]=>
          string(32) "View Training Exemption Requests"
          ["ActionItemUrl"]=>
          string(40) "../PendingExemptionRequests.aspx?wp=1"


...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
$xmlstring = $getUser->webserviceaction->any;
```

Then the loop should be:

```
foreach ($xml->User->ActionItems as $res) {
    echo "Title: " . $res->Title . "\n";
}
```

Simple XML is [case-sensitive.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353784/how-to-ignore-case-when-parsing-with-simplexml). And there is no `result` element, that's the tag of the top-level XML object.

Comment: I am able to get the xml code into $xmlstring with the above code,but still not able to read the corpname or the title inside the action items.

Comment: Updated the answer for that.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for your response. But,that doesn't work.I  believe action items is a list.Please correct me if I am wrong. echo $xml->result['corpname'] . "\n"; to get the corpname doesn't work either.

Comment: It doesn't look like a list in the XML you posted. Shouldn't there be separate `<actionitem>` elements within `<actionitems>` to group each one?

Comment: Never mind, I see you have another `<actionitems>` element after it.

Comment: It should be `$res->title`, not `$res['title']`, since `$res` is an XML element, not an array.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.foreach ($xml->result->user->inbox->actionitems as $res)
 echo "Title" . $res->title . "\n"; Still nothing shows up.

Comment: What do you see if you `var_dump($res)`?

Comment: It is not even going inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled, and are you getting any warnings or errors?

Comment: @I don't get any error. Just get NULL. I have updated the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77231/discussion-between-learner2011-and-barmar).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This one works.foreach ($xml->User->Inbox->ActionItems as $res)
{ echo "Title" . $res->Title . "\n"; }

Comment: I think you copied the XML wrong in the question, since Simple XML copies the case from the XML into the object. So if it says `Title` in the PHP object, it should be `<Title>` in the XML.